# How can we force google maps to match the city component

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

We are using the google Maps API to search to geocode an address.
The problem is that there is no way to break the API request address field to its components.

```
{
  address: string,
  location: LatLng,
  placeId: string,
  bounds: LatLngBounds,
  componentRestrictions: GeocoderComponentRestrictions,
  region: string
}
```

Since we can't break it to

```
{
  city: city
  street: street
  ...
}
```

we are getting strange results like e.g. "XX MyStreet st., MyCity"

Returns result where MyCity is the county and the city is a complete different city.

Is there a way to mark Google Maps that "MyCity" is a city and not a county.

Comment: Can I actually ask you to provide an example of the expected behavior versus an example of what you actually see in your results?

Comment: e.g. "Lilach 27,  Beer Sheva, Israel" The city should be Beer Sheva, but the result google maps returns is for Beer Sheva county.

Comment: We seem to be dealing with 2 issues here. The first one in which you ask if you can _force_google maps to match a city component. You cannot manipulate results coming from the server, no. But you can filter the information that you **want** in you application. The second question is about contesting the accuracy of that specific result. I won't go into detail on that but in that case there is no bug and it should be correct. The original question, at least to me, seems quite broad and I do not have a specific code snippet to help you with.

Comment: How can I filter? Assuming the user wrote Beer Sheva with some minor typo, I can distinguish between the two cases

Answer (score 2):

I've had a look at your sample address 'Lilach 27, Beer Sheva, Israel'. Let's check it in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DLilach%252027%252C%2520Beer%2520Sheva%252C%2520Israel

As you can see this address is clearly located inside the locality Omer. So address component `locality = Omer` seems to be correct here.

http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=0x1502676f35a89239:0xd3092fa77576ecf6

[image]

Referring to `administrative_area_level_2 = Be'er Sheva`, please note that Google has admin area with this name and you can see it here

http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=0x1501934b23af369b:0x31b08b946bdd4342

[image]

So, at this point it looks like the response is correct.

If you believe that administrative area should have another name or address should be located at different place, please [send feedback](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Be'er+Sheva,+Israel/@29.402322,36.3107235,8z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x1501934b23af369b:0x31b08b946bdd4342!8m2!3d30.829562!4d35.0388164!10m2!1e3!2e2) to Google. Also, note that the result type in geocoder is `RANGE_INTERPOLATED` and place ID is `EiHXnNeZ15zXmiAyNywg16LXldee16gsINeZ16nXqNeQ15w`. Typically these place IDs that start with E mean that address doesn't exist in database and was interpolated. You can report missing place to Google following the Help center:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846

I hope my answer clarifies your doubts!

Comment: But that is exactly the issue. Is there a way to indicate Google Maps that "Beer Sheva" is a city and not an administrative_area_level_2? We can't differ between a good result where google fix a typo in the city name and this wrong result

Comment: Do you know exact position of this address? Report it to Google data team and this should fix the issue in the future. I don't know any alternative way except adding a ROOFTOP address in their database.

Comment: I do know the exact and I reported it already, but that is not the issue, I have many similar examples.